# How I get webcam to my browser using rosbridge

Tags: mjpeg-server, gscam, rosbridge, ros-fuerte, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to show the webcam of my laptop to browser using ros. I see a better discussion at [here](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/show-video-from-robot-in-the-web-interface-based-on-rosjs-tutoirial-td3041132.html). I am uses ros-fuerte. The problem is that I cant able to install gscam , mjpeg_server in my system. How can I fix it on my ros fuerte. Please help me if there you know any good tutorial

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60670/how-i-get-webcam-to-my-browser-using-rosbridge/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi geek,

you can download the source of the mjpg-streamer. Look here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/develop

or here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/

download and make it. Then you can start the mjpg_streamer via shell so that it provides an apache server and a www directory, where it uploads the webcam pictures. Then you are able to include the created html or php file to your own website.
Maybe this helps you. I also use the mjpg_streamer and view the live stream with vlc or vlc plugin. Maybe this information helps you with your problem.

Best regards,
zumili

---

Originally posted by [zumili](https://answers.ros.org/users/3935/zumili/) with karma: 141 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1